# Customizing Weblogic HTTP extended logging format

Tags: logging, weblogic, weblogic12c, access-log

Currently in my weblogic server I have enabled HTTP logging. Below is the current configuration.

Format is "Extended".

Extended Logging Format Fields is "date time cs-method cs-uri sc-status time-taken c-ip"

So in access.log , logs are coming like

**current**

```
2018-01-18      11:39:19        GET     /test/service       200     1.406 127.0.0.1
2018-01-18      11:39:19        POST    /test/service      200 0.169    127.0.0.1
```

I wanted to change logging format in access.log like a key-value pair as mentioned below:

**expected**

```
date=2018-01-18      time=11:39:19        method=GET     uri=/test/service       status=200     duration=1.406      client_ip=127.0.0.1
date=2018-01-18      time=11:39:19        method=POST    uri=/test/service       status=200     duration=0.169      client_ip=127.0.0.1
```

Is it possible to modify the access log formatting as mentioned?

If possible , how to add these keys in Extended Logging Format Fields?

weblogic server versions: 12.1.2 & 12.2.1

Regards

Nadz

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explain in this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/CNFGD/web_server.htm#CNFGD207).
You can create your own custom fields and make them display whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you will have write some Java code.

`long getInvokeTime();` returns the starting time of `currentTimeMillis()`.

To get the length of time taken by the servlet to send the response to the client, use the following code:

```java
long milsec = System.currentTimeMillis() - metrics.getInvokeTime();

Float sec = new Float(milsec / 1000.0);
```